# Javascript responsiveness

Tags: javascript, responsive, screen-size

I have an array of items that are sliced and spliced that display as two columns in separate div's.

What I want is for one column's items to hop on over to the other column as the screen size gets smaller so that it appears as one column on a small screen. I'm only finding things online related to jquery, but I'd like to use vanilla JS. How do I go about doing this? Any help is very much appreciated!

```js
let arr = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'
];

let hey = arr.slice(4);
let heyArray = arr.splice(0, 4);

document.getElementById('displayA').innerHTML = '<li><a href="#">' + hey.join('</a></li><li><a href="#">') + '</a></li>';

document.getElementById('displayB').innerHTML = '<li><a href="#">' + heyArray.join('</a></li><li><a href="#">') + '</a></li>';
```

```css
div {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1.2em;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="displayA"></div>
<div id="displayB"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/bfoley650/pen/zYrvPmo

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: you can use display flex and flex-wrap in parent container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand but if it's responsiveness you want, then it's `css`'s problem and not `js`.

[Here you have](https://codepen.io/juanmnl/pen/oNbjrKp) how to achieve that in css, added some width and background color to the elements so it's visually clearer.

Basically, the idea is to have a `flex-container` that handles the direction those inner elements are rendered (row by default w/ flex-wrap) or set that container to column when the width of the screen is small enough.

Comment: Ok yeah so it sounds like there's no way to combine array elements based on screen size and the answer is through the css. Thanks!